# Join username of sender and receiver with message info

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a small user/messaging script as a learning exercise in PHP/MySQL. When I do the query to show the message, I would also like to output the user_username from the sender and the receiver. This is what I have so far:

```
  SELECT
    messages.*,
    user_receiver.user_username as message_receiver_username,
    user_sender.user_username as message_sender_username
  FROM
    messages
  INNER JOIN
    users user_receiver ON messages.message_receiver = user_receiver.user_id
   INNER JOIN
    users user_sender ON messages.message_sender = user_sender.user_id
```

Code on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5686aa/6

The problem is that this SQL code returns the usernames as "user_username" twice. **I want to return the usernames as "message_receiver_username" and "message_sender_username".**

New info: it seems the query works correct in phpMyAdmin, and it is SQL Fiddle that returns the original users table headers (user_username) instead of message_sender_username and message_receiver_username. Am I doing something wrong that makes the outcome different on different systems? Or is the query correct and SQL Fiddle wrong?

Here is some example content in the database, just to give you a better idea:

```
|-------------------------------|
| users                         |
|-------------------------------|
| user_id | user_username | ... |
|---------|---------------|-----|
| 1       | Max           |     |
| 2       | Maxim         |     |
| 3       | Maxim2        |     |
| ...     | ...           |     |
|-------------------------------|

|-------------------------------------------------------------|
| messages                                                    |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
| message_id  | ... | message_sender  | message_receiver  |...|
|-------------|-----|-----------------|-------------------|---|
| 1           |     | 1               | 2                 |   |
| 2           |     | 1               | 2                 |   |
| 3           |     | 2               | 3                 |   |
| ...         |     | ...             | ...               |   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: @Max It seems that this only happens in sqlfiddle. Mysql named the rows correctly

Comment: Also noticed that. Any idea? Something with the escaping?

Answer (score 0):

You should Write

```
     SELECT
    messages.*,
    user_receiver.user_username as 'message_receiver_username',
    user_sender.user_username as 'message_sender_username'
  FROM
    messages
  INNER JOIN
    users user_receiver ON messages.message_receiver = user_receiver.user_id
   INNER JOIN
    users user_sender ON messages.message_sender = user_sender.user_id
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: Please check the query results. I was wrong no need for more people to be

Comment: I Check the query. What happend @Naranca

Comment: You query isn't returning the values of the database instead it returns user_receiver.user_username which isn't what the query is supposed to return

Comment: Jahid26's answer makes SQL Fiddle return the right column headers, there's something going wrong with the escaping in SQL Fiddle I guess?

Comment: The right header but with wrong record values. I think SQL Fiddle has bug there.

Comment: With your code, the headers are named right in SQL Fiddle, but it now returns the wrong values in both phpMyAdmin and SQL Fiddle. Every username is "user_receiver.user_username" or "user_sender.user_username" instead of the actual username. Thanks for thinking though!

Comment: @max see my updated code and run it your machine.I ran it and it give the perfect output on my machine.This does not work in SQL Fiddle. Run it Your machine

Comment: I appreciate the effort but how is this a solution? My code already worked on my machine, just not on SQL Fiddle.